# How to close Expo terminal

Tags: expo

I'm starting learning expo, but when I start the process, I mean when I start expo on terminal I can't exit/stop I try using Control - C or Z but which out success.
I'm using Linux(UBUNTU), there is a easy way to close the terminal?

Answer (score 5):

Hi using **Control+C** is the proper way. As if you press it, Expo will detect this key press as exit command, so Expo will exit properly.
One thing that you can not using **Control+C** is maybe you are not do it in Expo terminal or Expo tab.

[image: expo exit]

Answer (score 1):

There is also a fun possibility that you use `fn` key by instinct instead of `ctrl`, when switching laptops. This happened to me today and it got me here.